# SSRS Report processing Error Dataset

Tags: ssrs-2008

An error occured during report processing (rsprocessing Aborted)
the expression referenced a non-existing field in the field collection (rsRuntimeErrorinException)

Comment: I think you misspeled the name of a field in some expression of your report. With the information you posted is impossible to know where the error is generated, provide the dataset fields and the report expressions in order to help you.

Comment: Hai alejandro you are right i misspelled the field in report expression..now i correct it..thank you so much